# MongoDb and Golang - $group and $match

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I am trying to $match my data after $group but it does not work.
I have db with **jobs**.
Every job has {**id**, **batchId**(a few jobs can belong to one batch), **createdAt**, finishedAt}.

I cant understand why I am getting empty result. I need to get the groups of the jobs with the same batchId that were created before CreatedAtTo parameter.
For saving date I used unix timestamp (so it is an integer)

My solution:

```
group := bson.M{
    "$group": bson.M{
        "_id":   "$batchid",
        "btime": bson.M{"$max": "$createdAt"},
        "doc":   bson.M{"$push": "$$ROOT"},
    },
}

match := bson.M{
    "$match": bson.M{
        "btime": bson.M{
            "$lte": CreatedAtTo},
    },
}

sort := bson.M{"$sort": bson.M{"btime": -1}}
limit := bson.M{"$limit": 1}

pipeline := []bson.M{group, match, sort, limit}
```

If I comment $match part it works, but not all together. And tried to perform in robo 3t. It works as well

```
    db.getCollection('jobs').aggregate(
    [
    {$group:{
        "_id":"$batchId",
        btime: { $max: "$createdAt"},
        bItems: { $push: "$$CURRENT" }
    }},
    {$match:{"btime": {"$lte": 10}}},
    {$sort:{"btime": -1}},
    {$limit:1},
    ])
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: The query needs the `$match` as the first stage of the pipeline.

Comment: But I need to match groups not jobs itself

Comment: Post a sample document.

Comment: @prasad_ , seriously you are a life saver. I tried everything and it didn't work. I don't know why I read this comment and it fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, make sure all your field is a valid date or use `$toDate`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$batchid",
      btime: {
        $max: "$createdAt"
      },
      doc: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      btime: {
        $gt: "2021-07-01T11:23:25.184Z"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eQB0FhfMDRK)